# Validation Rule on Case checking user's profile

Tags: validation-rule, default-value

I need to change picklist default value in the status of an external insurance case to "under review" if the users creating the record are Angelita, Caio or Ivan (Profile: External Insurance). Because these are responsible for acting on that case, causing it to be automatically under analysis.

At first we created this formula, but even specifying the profile, the rule is not allowing even them to change.

Formula:

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(Status),
    ISPICKVAL(Status, "Em análise"),
    NOT( $Profile.Id = "2F00eIa000000Lrb8" ) <- This is Seguros Externos Profile
)
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't hardcore IDs into validation rules unless necessary. The IDs differ for each sandbox. Try using developer name of the profile. Also, check the debug log to see the values that cause the validation rule to trigger.

Comment: I entered by the name of the profile instead of the ID and it worked, I also added the name of the profile of the System Adiministrator, but gave error to the administering users.

Comment: Check for any typos. Prefferably post the new formula here.

Comment: AND(
ISCHANGED(Status),
ISPICKVAL(Status, "Em Análise"),
NOT( $Profile.Name = "ITA - Seguro Externo" || $Profile.Name = "System Administrator")

)

Comment: Looks fine. What's your [default language at Company level](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96189/profile-name-in-validation-rule-not-working)?

Comment: My company language default in 
English.

Comment: I used the Administrator Role name and it worked.                                                   
 AND(                   
ISCHANGED(Status),
ISPICKVAL(Status, "Em Análise"),
NOT( $Profile.Name = "ITA - Seguro Externo" || $UserRole.Name = "Administrador")
)

Comment: The admin under which you've been testing probably has a different profile. That's my guess.